# Using Garmin GLO GPS receiver with Android application

Tags: android

Has anyone used the new Garmin GLO GPS receiver?  Has anyone successfully integrated it with their mobile application? I was interested in using it in order to get more accurate GPS coordinates in my Android application, but would like to get some feedback from others before I buy one.

The Garmin website does not mention if there is an API available to retreive the GPS coordinates, it simply states, "Using Bluetooth technology, GLO wirelessly pairs to your mobile device. Just set GLO within range of your mobile device and in moments you’ll be receiving GLO’s position data."

How can you retreive this position data?  Will applications on the device, such as Goolgle Maps, just get this data automatically?  Any info or feedback about the device would be greatly appreciated.

More info on the device can be found at the following link:

https://buy.garmin.com/shop/shop.do?pID=109827&ra=true

Todd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question seems to get a decent amount of traffic and could use a more thorough answer.

Garmin probably feels justified in saying this:

> Just set GLO within range of your mobile device and in moments you’ll be receiving GLO’s position data

because on iOS you can connect to the GLO and iOS uses the location information from the GLO to supply more accurate information to any device using the iOS location APIs.  Android has no such facility.  So, option one is to use an app that will read the NMEA data over BT and use that to set the mock location on your Android device (as Rodrigo said).  Option two is what I do in my app: connect to the GLO or other BT GPS from directly in the app.  Then I parse the NMEA lines myself and use that within the app.  The downside of this is that each app which uses location must implement this themselves.

Comment: have you tried the glo2? I'm thinking about purchasing for a multi platform app I'm developing. Are you able to share your code to read the NMEA data etc?

Comment: From the GLO2 store page: "Android devices require a GLO 2-enabled app to access GLO 2 functionalities." So it seems that the situation for Android is very similar to how it was for the GLO. I have not used a GLO2 though.

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me with this app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=googoo.android.btgps
It uses mock GPS location to inject the GLO's position.